# Posts in loop all show the same author when there are many authors

Tags: wp-query, loop, author

I am iterating through an array of post IDs `$ids`. All is displayed correctly except for the authors. Every post shows the same author, although the posts are by different authors. I can't seem to get this worked out...

```
<?php 
$ids = array();
$bookid = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'prefered_book', true ); 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'books',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => "$bookid",
        )
    )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
     while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
         $ids[]= $post->ID; 
     endwhile;
    }
?>

<?php
$bookdesc = get_term( $bookid , 'books');

if(count($ids)) : ?>
     <h5>Post about <?php echo $bookdesc->description; ?></h5>
     <ul>
     <?php foreach($ids as $id) : ?>
         <li>
             <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $id ); ?>">
                 <div class="Wrap">
                 <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id,'size-200') ); ?>
                 <?php if ($img) : ?>
                     <img class="smallImage" src="<?php echo $img ?>" />
                 <?php endif; ?>
                     <h3><?php echo get_the_title($id); ?></h3>
                     <h6>By <?php the_author($id); 
                             // Here it fails, incorrectly showing same author for every post
                     ?></h6> 

                 </div>
             </a>
         </li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echoing the ID inside the foreach loop to make sure it's getting the correct ID? The code looks fine, but I don't get the point of running a foreach loop if you already have a while loop with all the data you need.

Comment: You are right about the foreach, that was some old code I hadn't cleaned up. I removed the foreach and put everything inside the while loop, but the result is exactly the same. I am not sure I understand what ID should be echoed? The author ID? `print_r($ids);` gets all the correct post IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the bulk of your code into the loop proper. This part:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
     $ids[]= $post->ID; 
  endwhile;
}
```

When `the_post()` executes, it populates the `$post` global upon which a number of template functions depend. The problem is that you are running your `foreach` Loop but not resetting that global.

You could use `setup_postdata()` inside that `foreach` but I don't see the point. It looks like you can do the whole thing in the first Loop.

Comment: I followed your instructions and got rid of the foreach and put all the code in the loop but still get only the one author for all posts. I am calling the code in a template after the posts loop in a single.php template. Could that cause the problem?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. Now it works! Thanks!